# Can not setting password for root when installing linux be exploited?

Tags: linux, exploit, debian, root

Recently I've been thinking about how I installed my linux system (I went for debian). When I installed it, I chose not to enter password for root and only entered password for my user account. My question is whether it can be somehow exploited and is it possible to login as root when I didn't provide any password? I tried

```
su
Password:
```

but mine password obviously didn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about something or someone abusing this lapse and ending up logging in as root, don't worry: if `root` has no password set, no password will match and plain common login with that account (tty login, SSH login, X login, et al) will not be allowed.

But the account is still accessible: you can `sudo su` and become root. After that you can add a public key to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` and SSH-in as root.

But none of those methods will work when you don't have `sudo` powers, and you are probably the only one with that power on your system.